# Input Mask - Dynamic masking with decimals

Tags: javascript, validation, input, masking

I have written this code:

```
$(".mask_currency").inputmask({
    mask: "$ 9[99999].99",
    placeholder: "",
})
```

I am trying to input:

> 1.234  // This is Allowed
>
> 123.45 // This not allowed until I type all the 6 digits before decimal.

I want to make dynamic mask so that users can do 0.99 or 1234.12.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mask_currency").inputmask("9{1,5}.99");
```